# Why doesn't typescript detect an issue with this code?

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript...

```
function Component(props: number) {
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}

root.render(<Component thing={true} />);
```

`tsc --noEmit --watch`

Returns

`[8:28:01 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.`

When clearly the props are an object not a number.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: What is your configuration?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hassanshaikley/b01e28fb13efb746c6cb83b775d11ea3

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your issue](https://tsplay.dev/mAxM4N); that code should indeed error.  Without a [mre] it's hard to know how to advise.  Is there any way you could triple check that you are actually running the compiler on the file in question?  If you change the code to be invalid syntax, are there still no errors?  We really need more details about your setup.

Comment: So it caught an issue when I was like

const thing = (i: number) => i + 1;

thing("Hello")

Errored... It's just the React part that didn't work.

Comment: So should you tag this question with React?  Or other relevant components so the appropriate experts can look at it? (I know approximately zero about React, for example, but I watch the TypeScript tag)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be because it is in the root component. Outside of the root component type issues are detected. Not sure why.

Comment: This doesn't really constitute an answer to the question, does it?  It looks more like something you should edit into the question itself as part of the information needed to reproduce the issue.